# How to show time which keeps running in real time?

Tags: android

I want to display time which keeps running but this code just show the time when app is launched.

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
textView.setText(currentDateTimeString);
```

Comment: you want just static time or it suppose to be updating accordingly?

Comment: You need to use a Timer thread. Here's the JavaDoc: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer. There's also plenty of examples on the web. Basically use a recurring timer that fires every second.

Comment: You need to get time again after lets say 1 second if you're showing in this format
`hh:mm:ss`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it with handlers as below:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // display your time here...
          String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
          textView.setText(currentDateTimeString);
    }
}, 1000); // here 1 seconds to refresh time after 1 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Calendar class which include what you are looking for with method might be

```
getTime()
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html